# Where to put the business logic of a Chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, business-logic

I am developing my first Chrome extension and have a question related to where to put the main logic (and things like API calls).

I use React for the popup, so an option is to put all logic in these React components. This is what I would do if was making a normal web app.

But with extensions you also have background scripts. So if I for example have to implement OAuth logging-in logic, what is the best place to put all the code?

Comment: If you store the token in chrome.storage or localStorage, you can do everything in the popup script without a background script. The popup runs each time it's shown so you'll read the token and use it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple logic: All the API calls should be done in background script and DOM manipulation in content script.